# How can I use external variables in eval in Scheme?

Tags: lisp, scheme, eval

I am trying something out in Scheme for fun.  I'm trying to make an Area function that gets the type of the thing it's operating on and then calls a different function depending on the type of object.  Here's my code:

```
(define (area object)
  (if (not (null? (eval (word 'area- (get-type object)))))
      (eval (list (word 'area- (get-type object)) 'object))
      #f
  )
)
```

Scheme doesn't like this because it says object is an unbound variable.  No, I can't take the quote away because then it's actually placing the value there and then Scheme complains that the list is malformed.

What can I do to use the value in object within eval?

Note:  Scheme apparently grabs the global variable "object" just fine, so it's basically ignoring that it's inside a function.

Some information for a related language is here: http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/eval.html, which seems to indicate that there isn't a solution in Scheme, but if you know of one I'd like to hear it.

Comment: Like Eli said, using a name-based dispatch mechanism is totally fugly and broken. Scheme isn't PHP. Just don't go there. :-P

Comment: Why is it not correct to do it this way, Chris?

Answer (score 3):

There isn't one -- and that's a feature.  `eval` is doing an evaluation of a form that was generated dynamically at runtime.  So, if it needs to know about local bindings, then you'd need to compile `(lamba (x) x)` and `(lambda (y) y)` differently -- because the name matter.  But this is just the tip, there's a whole bunch of issues around implementing this kind of feature.

As for your problem -- even if it was possible to do what you want to, it's a fragile solution that depends on name.  Remember that in Scheme you can use functions like any other value -- so instead of calling `get-type` and combining it with some symbol to get a name, make your objects contain the function that is needed (which at that point would be better called "method").

Something like:

```
(define (area object)
  ((get-area-method object) object))
```

Obviously doing this means that there's little point in not going the whole way with:

```
(define (area object)
  (get-area object))
```

which is just

```
(define area get-area)
```

But the first might be more typical of a general OO-like system, with a way to get methods, so it might be useful for you.  That direction could take you to:

```
(define (area object)
  ((get-method object 'get-area) object))
```

Answer (score 2):

Racket has [classes and methods](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/classes.html), and you should use it!

```
(define circle%
  (class object%
    (init radius)
    (define r radius)
    (super-new)
    (define/public (area)
      (* pi r r))))

(define rectangle%
  (class object%
    (init width height)
    (define w width)
    (define h height)
    (super-new)
    (define/public (area)
      (* w h))))

(define unit-circle (new circle% [radius 1]))
(define unit-square (new rectangle% [width 1] [height 1]))

(send unit-circle area)   ; => 3.141592653589793
(send unit-square area)   ; => 1
```

*Much* less hacky than name-based dispatch.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there IS a way to do what I wanted to do in Scheme.  Here is the code:

```
(define (area object)
  ((eval (list 'identity (word 'area- (get-type object)))) object)
)
```

Basically the trick is this: Because eval only knows about global variables, I can still use the identity function within eval to return the value of a global variable.  The global variable I'm interested in in this case is a function, which is just like any other variable.  I can then return this value and use it as the procedure to call on my original argument.  This lets me construct the name of the variable I want to get from global scope and get and use the procedure contained in that variable, accomplishing the result I was looking for.

Here's a cleaner version:

```
(define (area object)
  ((get-function (word 'area- (get-type object))) object)
)

(define (get-function function)
  (eval (list 'identity function)))
```

Apparently the is-not-null part will not work, however, because trying to get the identity of a function that doesn't exist causes an unbound variable error.  So, still need to be careful to call the operator on a type that supports it.

Comment: This is very wrong.  Start from the fact that using `'identity` is redundant (you can just `eval` the symbol directly -- same result), and from there you get to your "clean" version of `get-function` which is itself just an identity function.

Comment: But how do I eval a constructed symbol?  Maybe (eval (list (append something?  Problem with that is, eval constructs a procedure from the list, so if I (eval 'thing) it really calls (thing) with no arguments, rather than just returning the value of thing.

Comment: No, that's wrong.  `(eval 'x)` just returns the value of the global `x`, it doesn't call any function.  (But see my answer -- you shouldn't use `eval` for such things.  It's guaranteed to be a bad solution.)

Comment: Good catch, I thought eval was evaluating it, but that was because I was passing it inside a list which makes eval call it.  Thanks for that.  You may want to submit a solution that modifies my version and I'll select it.

Comment: I don't know what solution you're expecting -- the whole concept of using `eval` the way you want to use it is (still) fundamentally broken.

Comment: Answering that, in a way that is more in-depth than my answer above, is not something that I can do in a comment...  But it's also not needed: just google around and you'll find a ton of discussions on the subject.  In any case, the bottom line is that for your needs (an OO-like system) just using function values would work out much better.